# Rename Column in Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

I know I can accomplish my objective with this process:

1. Create new column
2. Update new from old
3. Drop old

I am looking for a way to do this with one command.  I know that `remane object` works at the table level.  For example, I can do this:

```
rename object Test.danPatient to dimPatient
```

But these all fail with various error messages:

```
rename object Test.dimPatient.City to Test.dimPatient.Town
rename object Test.dimPatient.City to Town
rename object DatabaseName.Test.dimPatient.City to Town
rename object DatabaseName.Test.dimPatient.City to DatabaseName.Test.dimPatient.Town
```

Plus, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql), `sp_rename` is not supported by Azure Data Warehouse.  My unsuccessful efforts to use it suggest that the web page is accurate.

Am I attempting the impossible?

Comment: Hey Dan. Out of curiosity, why are you attempting to rename your column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your correct that right now you cannot rename a column in this fashion. The fastest way to do this today is to run a [CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-as-select-azure-sql-data-warehouse) operation. Your statement would look something like this:

`CREATE TABLE Test.DimPatientNew AS 
SELECT
   City [town],
   <all other columns>
FROM
   Test.DimPatient;`

You can add your feedback to our public feedback forum here:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse

Rename a column request: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516/suggestions/18434083

Comment: Thank you for that.  I added a request to enable Intellisense,  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/33728026-enable-intellisense-with-ssms.  I was surprised nobody had done it before.

Comment: Thanks Dan. We appreciate the feedback and take your input very seriously.

Answer (score 3):

`sp_rename` and column is now supported in Azure Synapse Analytics. So you can use:

```
sp_rename '[schema].[table].[old_column]', '[new_column]' , 'COLUMN';
```

Ref: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/rename-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7)